# NPM read-only tokens keep getting deleted

Tags: npm, auth-token

Why do my read-only tokens keep getting deleted from npm's site?

Repro steps:

I create a new read-only token using npm's web portal:

[image]

It is successfully created.

[image]

I then store the token in my command line config (`.zshrc` in my case)

`export NPM_TOKEN=f00ba4ba-2f00-ba4b-a2f0-0ba4ba2f00ba`

And reference it in my `.npmrc` (in my project folder).

This works great. `npm whoami` works as intended, and I'm able to pull from our private repo.

...for a while...

A little while later, it's just gone. Pulling from our private repo fails with a `404`. `npm whoami` returns a 402. And the token is gone from the npm web interface.

I thought maybe they have a one hour life time, but I can't see anywhere is the documentation where it says they have any expire time at all.

Is there an `npm` command that a side-effect of deleting an auth-token?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. I must have run `npm logout` from the command line at some point.

Some context about how `npm login` and `logout` work:

When you run `npm login` it creates a "publish" token and stores it in your `.npmrc` *in your user's home directory*.

When you run `npm logout` it destroys that token; removes it from npm's auth system and delete's it from the `.npmrc` in your home folder.

But it's worth digging a little deeper into how npm auth works.

When you do anything from the command line that needs auth permissions from npm, it first looks at the `.npmrc` *in your project directory* to see if there's an auth token in there. If there is, it uses that one when checking the npm auth server. Only if there's no auth token in that `.npmrc` does it check `.npmrc` in your user's home folder. (I'm sure it's more complex than this; I'm just saying, it checks the project folder before it checks your home folder).

But it does the same thing when you run `npm logout`. If there's an auth token in `.npmrc` in your project folder it assumes that's your identity, and invalidates that token.

So, that's what happened to my, I believe.

1. I referenced the token in `.npmrc` in my project folder.
2. I ran `npm logout` at some point. (I don't remember why I did this, but I must have – I've since replicated this behavior).
3. When I ran `logout` npm used the token in my project folder as my identity, and invalidated the token. It didn't care that it was a "read-only" token and not a "publish" token. Nor did it care that the token had been generated manually via the web portal instead of programatically via the cli.

Hopes this helps someone.

Comment: How did I not know about this? Thanks for documenting it. This is a really bad usability issue IMO.